# VBA Userform hides specific Workbook but alow to use other Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a fully  functional  Userform and was able to write some code to "Hide" the Worbook and shows the application:

**Code in Workbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 (userformname).Show

End Sub
```

**Code in Userform**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

 ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True

End Sub
```

This has work as intended but does not allow to work in any other Workbooks that might be opened, for other purpuses. To solve this I've added this code but is giving me some errors I am unable to resolve

**Code in Workbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

 (userformname).Show

End Sub
```

**Code in Userform**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 If Application.Windows.Count > 1 Then 'more than one workbook open: Hide workbook only
  
   Application.ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

 Else 'only one workbook open: Hide application

   Application.Visible = False

 End If

End Sub
```

**Error**

[image]

In short I have Workbook 1 that contains my code and userform,  when i open it  only Workbook1 should be hidden and locked while other non related workbooks  remains open and i am able to use them as normal.

Also is it possible to show the Userform  in the windows when Alt+Tab is done?

Comment: Maybe you  could open your form modeless, i.e. `(userformname).Show vbModeless`. Otherwise please describe what you mean with _but is giving me some errors I am unable to resolve_ as we do not know what errors you get.

Comment: Run time error '13' Type mismatch.    It only shows the error when i  use 
'(userformname.Show)' in  the workbook

Comment: Do you really use the brackets: `(userformname)`?

Comment: No I don't,  its for example purposes only.

Comment: Ok, I thought so, just wanted to make sure. But this also means I am out of further hints as your code is working for me when using vbModeless.

Comment: Yeah I  used your sugestion and it work perfectly Thanks!